# Proving a Subset is Dense

Tags: general-topology

I am new to phrasing things as is done in topology so was hoping someone can tell me if my interpretation is correct here:

To prove a subset $A$ of a topological space $X$ is dense in $X$ one must show that for all $x$ in $X$ such that $x \not\in A$ there exists a function $f(x,N) \in A$ such that $\lim _{N\rightarrow  \left| A \right| }(f \left( x,N \right)) =x$

For example the rational numbers are a dense subset of the real numbers because every real number either is a rational number or has a rational number arbitrarily close to it, for this case $f$ would be Diophantine approximation, and demonstrating this to be capable of approximating any irrational number to any desired precision with a rational algebraic expression is hence effectively proving that $\mathbb Q$ is a dense subset of $\mathbb R$.

Thanks for helping in advance

Comment: What is $|A|$? ${}{}$

Comment: What do you mean by $|A|$? Also, your definition probably works with metric spaces, where you can define "closeness" in numbers in $\mathbb{R}$, but in a more general setting, you should be able to formulate limits in terms of open subsets only (which is possible). For $\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{R}$ though, this defintion should suffice.

Comment: I meant the cardinality of $A$

Comment: Um... so what is $\lim_{N\to |A|}$ when e.g. $A$ is uncountable?

Comment: infinity? :-( no ok I see your point

Comment: what I think I meant is that an infinite number of points in $A$ can always be used to approximate to any element of $X$ not in $A$

Comment: which is not quite what I stated with that limit thing

Comment: I think it will be easier if you have a precise definition to work with. Like the other commented above, using sequence is not the most general definition.

Comment: ok thanks I'll read a bit more

Comment: Your limit statement is sloppy at best, it’s easiest to show $A$ is dense whenever $O$ is a (non-empty) (basic) open subset of $X$, $O \cap A \neq \emptsyet$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show a subset $A$ of $X$ is dense (in general), we need to show that every non-empty (basic) open subset $O$ of $X$ contains a point of $A$. So for the reals it suffices to note that in any open interval $(a,b)$ with $a < b$ contains a rational number. We don't have to find some proscribed approximating function etc. And a set can be dense but have *no sequences* in it converge to points outside it, even in pseudocompact normal spaces. Dense is just that every non-empty open set intersects it, so in that sense the set "lives everywhere". In a metric space we *can* show that $A$ is dense iff for all $x \notin A$ there is a sequence $(a_n)_n$ from $A$ converging to $x$, and so maybe that's where the OP gets his inspiration.

Comment: Thanks yes I did previously acknowledge that my limit statement was silly at best, basically this Wikipedia article under the subheading "Ratios of consecutive values" states that two sets have been proven to be dense in two real spaces, I was unable to find these papers and have a lot of very similar sets in my notes that I now feel that ascertaining which spaces they are dense and which ones they are not to be very important, and I can't keep avoiding topology anymore https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function